# How do i get an input value inside a js function?

Tags: javascript

So i have this problem. I have an input which a user can type in. I want that input inside a javascript function. Let me demonstrate.

```js
function run() {
  // I want the value of #input here
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><button onclick="run()" id="run">RUN</button>
```

Disclamer: I do not want to get the value, i want it so that the value inserts in the code, as a code-editor typed it.

Comment: Have a look at `eval`.

Comment: do you mean, write a code in the textarea then click "RUN" and it should be executed? if yes, follow @JonasW. comment, it can help you

Comment: But this is not jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function like this:

`eval(document.getElementById('input').value)`

**DEMO**

```js
function run() {
  eval(document.getElementById('input').value)
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><button onclick="run()" id="run">RUN</button>
```

**BUT**

be aware of the [evilness](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) of eval!

Comment: This is probably the only sort of solution that will work.  But just remember that the user might enter `launchTheBombs(); stealYourGirlfriend(); dangleAParticiple();` or other unsavory code you wouldn't like to have run.  When people say "`eval` is evil", there is a real reason.

Answer (score 0):

you can use eval() method to execute code snippet.

```js
function run() {
  var text_area = document.getElementById('input').value;
  try {
        eval(text_area);
  }
  catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
  }  
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="5" cols="30">console.log("test snippet");</textarea>
<button onclick="run()" id="run">RUN</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

eval alternative:

```
function run() {
    new Function([], document.getElementById('input').value)(); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried jquery?

```
$('#run').on('click', function() {
  console.log($('#input').val())
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pigeontoe/6571rzc2/

Comment: This question is *not* tagged with [tag:jquery]